# jQuery get the select tag value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to get the select tag value. I need to alert the text value "ART"
Any Idea?

```
<select class='category_drop43' value="ART"><option value='test'>Test</option></select>


$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.category_drop43').change(function() {       

        var keyword = $('select' this ).val();
                alert(keyword);
        });             
})
```

Comment: What is `'.category_drop43'`?  Why does the `select` element have a `value` attribute?  Is that even valid, and how might it conflict with the values on the `option` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.val()` instead of `.value()`:

```
var keyword = $(this).val();
```

or better using pure javascript to get the value:

```
var keyword = this.value;
```

Please note that `select` does not have `value` attribute as well as your `select` don't have any class name as `.category_drop43`, so you can either add this class to your `select`

```
<select class="category_drop43"><option value='test'>Test</option></select>
```

or target the `select` element using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function() {       
        var keyword = this.value;
        alert(keyword);
    });             
});
```

---

`value` is invalid HTML attribute for `select` element, you can use `data-*` HTML5 attribute instead:

```
<select class="category_drop43" data-value="ART"><option value='test'>Test</option></select>
```

then you can use `.data()` to retrieve the value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function() {       
        var keyword = $(this).data('value');
        alert(keyword);
    });             
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6U6PF/)**

Comment: it's still giving me the value of the option selected.

Comment: @Grasper Did you check my demo?

Comment: yeah, I change attr to data and it's working great, thanks a lot